# Dual of a stable locally free subsheaf is a locally free quotient sheaf

Tags: vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds, sheaf-cohomology, positivity

Let $X$ be a compact connected Kähler manifold, of dimension $d\geq3$, with Hermitian metric $\omega$; let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $r\geq2$.

By [1] definition 1.2:

> A line bundle $L$ on $X$ is said *numerically effective* (*nef*, for short) if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth Hermitian metric $h_{\epsilon}$ on $L$ such that
>   \begin{equation*}
> \Omega_{h_{\epsilon}}(L)\geq-\epsilon\omega;
> \end{equation*}
>   that is the curvature form $\Omega_{h_{\epsilon}}(L)$ of the Chern connection on $L$ (with respect to $h_{\epsilon}$) can have an arbitrary negative part.

By [1] definition 1.9:

> $E$ is *nef* if the tautological bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$ is *nef*. $E$ is *numerically flat* (*nflat*, for short) if $E$ and $E^{\vee}$ are both nef.

In the proof of theorem 1.18, one assumes $E$ nflat; let $F$ be a reflexive subsheaf of $E$ of minimal rank $p$ of degree $0$, one proves that $\det F$ is a line bundle and by [1] lemma 1.20 $F$ is a subbundle of $E$. By assumption, $F$ is a ($\omega$-)stable subbundle of $E$.

The authors state that $F^{\vee}$ is a locally free quotient sheaf of $E^{\vee}$!

**Question:** Why does this hold?

I understand that $\left(E_{\displaystyle/F}\right)^{\vee}\equiv\mathcal{Q}^{\vee}$ is a reflexive subsheaf of $E^{\vee}$ (cfr. [2] proposition V.5.18 or this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17277/dual-of-torsion-free-reflexive-coherent-sheaf/17317#17317)), on an open subset $U$ of $X$ it is locally free, so $\mathcal{E}xt^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}\left(\mathcal{Q},\mathcal{O}_X\right)_{|U}=0$ and $F^{\vee}_{|U}$ is a locally free quotient sheaf of $E^{\vee}_{|U}$.

**Remark:** For the cases of complex curves and Kähler surfaces, the previous statement holds by [2] corollary V.5.20; because, without change the names, $\textrm{codim}(X\setminus U)\geq3$.

---

[1] J.-P. Demailly, T. Peternell, M. Schneider - *Compact complex manifolds with numerically effective tangent bundles*, J. Algebraic Geom. **3** (1994) 295-345

[2] S. Kobayashi (1987) *Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles*, Iwanami Shoten Publishers and Princeton University Press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a *subbundle* of $E$, then one has a natural surjection of vector bundles $E^*\to F^*\to 0$ induced by the restriction map. This is equivalent to saying the $F^*$ is a quotient bundle of $E^*$ (by the kernel of the map above, which is a vector subbundle of $E^*$), or if you prefer, $\mathcal O_X(F^*)$ is a locally free quotient of $\mathcal O_X(E^*)$.